# possible to group urlpatterns of the same app?django

Tags: python, django, variables, url, design-patterns

I know that in each app, we can use our own urlpatterns and include it in the main project / app using include.

I am wondering if an app have a few different urls, is there a way to group it?

for example

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^user/hello/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^user/there/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^user/here/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^user/that/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^user/mini/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^user/max/$', hello.asView(), 

    url(r'^bb/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^bb/hello/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^bb/there/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^bb/here/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^bb/that/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^bb/mini/$', hello.asView(), 
    url(r'^bb/max/$', hello.asView(), 
]
```

please ignore all the `hello.asView()`  but I am wondering if there's a way to group all the `user` and `bb` so if there are more url, I don't need to keep on typing `user` or `bb` again?

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matching patterns

```
url(r'^user/(?P<page>[\w-]+)/$', hello.asView(),
```

and in your view you can check if page is valid. Let's say you have a page list. You just do this:

```
def get(self, page):
    page_list = ['hello', 'there', 'here']
    if page not in page_list:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```